# Using tidyr::fill() to fill in blank dates

Tags: r, tidyr

Trying to use `tidyr::fill()` to fill in the blanks in the `inception_date` and `expiry_date` fields (filling in a downward direction) in a test data set:

[image]

Having trouble. If I run, for example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test <- test %>% 
  mutate(new_inception_date = fill(inception_date, .direction = "down"))
```

I get an error message

```
no applicable method for 'fill' applied to an object of class "Date"
```

Does `fill()` not work with date fields? Is there a workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: `fill()` takes the entire dataframe as its first argument. So don’t use it inside `mutate()`; instead try `test %>% fill(inception_date, expiry_date)`.

Comment: For future reference, please provide your data in a copy-pasteable form using `dput()`, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/17303805). See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805) for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, `fill` works on a frame at a time. From `?fill`:

```
Usage:

     fill(data, ..., .direction = c("down", "up", "downup", "updown"))
     
Arguments:

    data: A data frame.

     ...: <'tidy-select'> Columns to fill.

.direction: Direction in which to fill missing values. Currently either
          "down" (the default), "up", "downup" (i.e. first down and
          then up) or "updown" (first up and then down).
```

Quick demo of its usage:

```r
df <- data.frame(date = Sys.Date() + replace(1:8, c(1, 4, 7), NA))
df
#         date
# 1       <NA>
# 2 2023-02-04
# 3 2023-02-05
# 4       <NA>
# 5 2023-02-07
# 6 2023-02-08
# 7       <NA>
# 8 2023-02-10
df %>%
  fill(date)
#         date
# 1       <NA>
# 2 2023-02-04
# 3 2023-02-05
# 4 2023-02-05
# 5 2023-02-07
# 6 2023-02-08
# 7 2023-02-08
# 8 2023-02-10
```